# Want to exclude specific files with dir findstr

Tags: batch-file, cmd, dir, findstr

I want to find all *.csv files within a folder-structure except 2 files

This is my code

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%i IN ('dir /b /s *.csv | findstr /v /i  "\combinedold.csv" | findstr /v /i "\combined.csv"')
```

The 2 files are "combined.csv" and "combinedold.csv".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic command should be something like

```dos
dir /s /b /a-d *.csv | findstr /v /i /e /c:"\\combinedold.csv" /c:"\\combined.csv"
```

Now, to include it inside a `for /f` command, it is necessary to escape non quoted special characters (the pipe in this case), so it becomes

```dos
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('
    dir /s /b /a-d *.csv ^| findstr /v /i /e /c:"\\combinedold.csv" /c:"\\combined.csv"
') do echo %%i
```

Comment: Hey there, thanks for the fast help :)
so put the code into my bat, but it still has problems...to concrete the problem, i can show u the rest of the code
`for /f "tokens=*"  %%i IN ('dir /b /s *.csv') do (
if !cnt!==1 (
more "%%i" >> combined.csv
) else if "%%i" NEQ combined.csv (
more +1 "%%i" >> combined.csv
set /a cnt+=1`

So, i want to merge all csvs into one csv which is named combined.csv. When starting the bat-file again, it shall ignore the combined.csv, and the combinedold.csv because when i start the bat a second time, it moves the combined.csv into combinedold.csv

Comment: @n1no91, it seems you have most of the process coded. What is the problem? Does it fit into the original question? If not, please, start a new question for the new problem. Comments are too limited.